# How to access the refs of a child element from a parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In an app made of one component, my basic approach is as follows:

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
  onMounted,

} = Vue;
const App = {

  setup() {
    const myinput = ref(null)

    const focusMe = () => {
      myinput.value.focus()
    }

    return {
      myinput,
      focusMe
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input />
  <input ref="myinput" />
  <input />
  <button @click="focusMe">
  focus
  </button>
</div>
```

I now need, **from a parent component**, to access the `ref` of an element in a **child component**. A typical use would be a sticky focus button on the main page (defined in the very top component) that sets the focus to an `input` element in a child component.

**My question:** how can I access the `ref` of that element (from within the parent component)

Comment: This is generally a bad practice. If a child allows that, it should have public method for this. So it's `focusMe` that needs to be accessed, not an element

Comment: @EstusFlask: Thanks. Would you know where I can find information about a public method exposed by a Vue component (I never heard about that but I understand the idea.  It is just that I would not know how to call it from the parent (because I never heard about it :))

Comment: I misinterpreted the example. Do you really need to pass the children from the page as `<div id="app"><input />...`. For your case there's likely no good way to do this, as it lies outside common Vue usage. You may need to query elements from DOM.

Comment: @EstusFlask: I ended up using a prop in the child, each modification triggers the focus on the element (in the child). This way I disconnect the logic of focusing from the request of a focus (done in the parent). Thanks for the reflexions.